# One selector for multiple feature states

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have 2 pages which uses same reducers and state. So i wanna know how to use ngrx selectors in components so they use correct feature state like reducers are doing in components.

page1.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('page-1', PageReducer)
  ]
})
```

PageComponent.ts

```
this.store.dispatch(PageActions.getUsers()); //Everything works fine, users are stored in "page-1" state
this.store.pipe(SelectUsers); // Doesn't work. I wanna select users from feature state "page-1"
```

page2.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('page-2', PageReducer)
  ]
})
```

PageComponent.ts

```
this.store.dispatch(PageActions.getUsers()); //Everything works fine, users are stored in "page-2" state
this.store.pipe(SelectUsers); // Doesn't work. I wanna select users from feature state "page-2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Import `select` from the `@ngrx/store`

```
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
```

you forgot to wrap the `SelectUsers` in the `select` method.

```
this.users$ = this.store.pipe(select(SelectUsers));
```

`this.users$` will be an observable that can be bind on the UI with `async` pipe

e.g.

```
<div>{{ (users$ | async)?.name }}</div>
```

I am assuming you have wire-up the selectors properly so this should work.

### You can combine the multiple state under one selector

```
const getPageOneState = createFeatureSelector('page-1');
const getPageTwoState = createFeatureSelector('page-2');

export const SelectUser = createSelector(
    getPageOneState,
    getPageTwoState,
    (pageOneState, pageTwoState) => {
      return { ...whatever you want to return... }
    }
)
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. My selector works fine, i just doesn't know how to make it so it uses feature state declared in page module.

Comment: `SelectUsers` is named same for both features and used on the same page, you have to rename them to be unique.

Comment: Thats the problem, i wanna use one selector for both feature states (like reducers).

Comment: updated the answer where you can combine multiple states under one selector